# Question about Aaronson Scott Quantum Computing Since Democritus

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In the chapter on sets:

> Equality rules: $x=x, x=y$ implies $y=x, x=y$ and $y=z$ implies
>   $x=z$, and $x=y$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$ are all valid.

where $f$ is a function.

But how do we know for example that $f(x)=x+1$ is a function without resorting to circular reasoning?

Example: in highschool our teacher used to do the following to prove that $f(x)=x+1$ is indeed a function : Another way he does is assume $x=y$, then $x+1=y+1$ so $f(x)=f(y)$ so he already used the fact that $f$ is a function hence reasoning circular!

Comment: I don't understand your question; or where you find circularity in the reasoning.

Comment: For a function $f$, it is not true that $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$. Take $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: I can't see the connection between this statement which is false for a function and proving that $f=x+1$ is a function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila 
Example: in highschool our teacher used to do the following to prove that $f(x)=x+1$ is indeed a function : Another way he does is assume $x=y$, then $x+1=y+1$ so $f(x)=f(y)$ so he already used the fact that $f$ is a function hence reasoning circular!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I edited the question

Comment: What's the teacher's definition of a function ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust a function is the set of pairs of numbers $f=\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...\}$ such that if $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are in $f$ then $b=c$

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you think?

Comment: I think that you haven't defined what $+$ and $1$ are in this context, so instead of saying that this is circular, I will say that this is not well-defined yet. After you define $+$ as a binary operator, and write the axioms that you expect $+$ to satisfy, then we can talk about whether or not some proof is circular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,x+1)$ and $(y,y+1)$ be any two pairs in $f$. If $x=y$, then $x+1=y+1$ then by the definition of a function, $f(x)=x+1$ is a function.

What is missing in the argument is some definition for the successor "$+1$", or the rule that $x=y\implies x+1=y+1$.

Comment: But you're already supposing that $f$ is a function, whereas i want to show that $f$ is a function.

Comment: Where do I make this supposition ?

Comment: Forget that: what about this: for f(x)=sin(x) If $x=y$ then $sin(x)=sin(y)$ thus $f(x)=f(y)$. How would you prove that?

Comment: The same way, with a proper definition of $\sin$.